# Swift Firebase Storage.storage().reference(forURL: ) not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Suddenly my reference to to my Storage to retrieve images to share is not working anymore. It was literally just working 30 minutes ago but being very inconsistent. Do I have to add new security rules or something? But I guess welcome to programming where code magically stops working lol.

```
let ref = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: pictureImage)
        ref.getData(maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024, completion: {(data, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("image could not be downloaded")
            } else {
                if let imgData = data {
                    if let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                        objectsToShare.append(img)
                        print("image downloaded")
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

**Update**

When I use this call it works, yet my "getData" call has stopped working...

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: pictureImage)
            storageRef.delete(completion: { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    print("Successful Delete")
                }
            })
```

Comment: Reading the firebase document, I believe I now need to add security rules for my "maxSize".... can someone help me why I need to do this now, or even help me fix this problem? I can delete post's which uses the same URL but not being able to download them to share...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same is working for me

```
func downloadImageUserFromFirebase(Link:String) {

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Link)

        storageRef.getData(maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
            if error == nil {

                if let imgData = data {
                    if let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                        print("got imagedata \(String(describing: imgData))")
//                        objectsToShare.append(img)
                        print("image downloaded")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("ERROR DOWNLOADING IMAGE : \(String(describing: error))")
            }
        }
    }
```

Seems like you Had made some changes in your Rules

Comment: My rules are the same as they are for when I started added to my storage database. For some reason the URL works for all the other calls just not downloading the image...

Comment: Try checking url are actually working or not by printing them in console ? u need to check that is it a valid url or url you are sending is not empty

Comment: I will give that a try and get back to you if that gets me to solve this problem

Comment: Yeah, the URL's do show up and work, yet not for downloading the image anymore. I didn't change my rules or my code. I've tested it in parts of the app I am not working on that have worked before and it doesn't download the image...

Comment: Like, when I want to display the images on a feed and collection view it all works yet now for some reason downloading the image doesn't work anymore

Comment: All of the images load correctly and everything, just went through the whole app... this is really odd

Comment: so you mean url works when checked but objectsToShare doesn't contain anything when you try it ?

Comment: if possible can you share project file ?

Comment: like, I've tried multiple different images that have worked before to get them to download. When I do my "Share" button now, before the caption wouldn't appear and only the image would. Now no image, but caption is present.

Comment: This is a pretty large project not sure how I could share it with you

Comment: Dude.... that's so weird your code works!!! mine doesn't for some reason WTF?!?!?!?!

Comment: Your's downloads the image

Answer (score 1):

Well for me the problem was that I was missing the `-ObjC` flag in *Other linker flags* in my app's build settings.